# Apply opacity mask and annotate watermark with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm finding a way to apply a watermark and opacity mask for an image using imagemagick.

**Source**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Thank you all for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks emcconville for a nice solution but still it needs the rectangle of the image size. I've found a better solution that we don't need to specify rectangle of the image.

```
convert a.png -brightness-contrast -60x-50 -pointsize 120 -gravity center -draw "fill white text 0,0 'SOLD'" b.png
```

I hope this would be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty basic, and fun, stuff with ImageMagick. Examples and details in the article "[Annotating](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/)". Opacity mask & watermarking may be overkill when simple annotation & drawing will work.

```bash
convert source.png \
    -fill "#0009" -draw 'rectangle 0,0,450,335' \
    -fill white -pointsize 64 -gravity Center -annotate 0 "SOLD" \
    sold.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've found a better solution so we don't have to care about the size of source image.

`convert a.png -brightness-contrast -60x-50  -pointsize 120 -gravity center -draw "fill white text 0,0 'SOLD'" b.png`

Comment: Absolutely! Adjusting the contrast will resolve the need to know the image dimensions. Please post your solution as an answer, and accept it.